# Issues writing beautifulsoup output to .txt

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping web articles with beautifulsoup. The output is printing correctly, but is not writing the complete output to the file. It seems to break once it hits a quoted sentence. Below is the relevant code. Any insights would be tremendously helpful.

Use this URL to replicate the results: http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/03/06/us-syria-crisis-assad-insight-idUSBREA250SD20140306

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import codecs

# Ask user to enter URL
url = raw_input("Please enter a valid URL: ")

# Make sure file is clear for new content
open('ctp_output.txt', 'w').close()

# Open txt document for output
txt = open('ctp_output.txt', 'w')

# Parse HTML of article, aka making soup
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

# retrieve all of the paragraph tags
with open('ctp_output.txt', 'w'):
    for tag in soup.find_all('p'):
        txt.write(tag.text.encode('utf-8') + '\n' + '\n')

# Close txt file with new content added
txt.close()
```

Comment: "not writing the complete output to the file" - what is it writing? What is being left out?

Comment: Opening a file in 'w' mode is enough to truncate it. You don't need to close and reopen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Article scraping with beautifulsoup: scraping all <p> tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22240253/article-scraping-with-beautifulsoup-scraping-all-p-tags)

Comment: alecxe - that was my post from yesterday. I thought the problem was a result of something else. I only left it up so the person who took time to answer it would still get credit for helping. This may be bad SO form, I'm new to the community.

Comment: current output: 
*Everything up to and not including this paragraph"The president said: ‘If there is a popular demand for me to be nominated, I will run. I will not abandon my national duty'," said Shi'ite Muslim cleric Al Sayyed Fadi Burhan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you should encode what you are trying to write in utf8:

```
to_write = tag.get_text() + "\n"
f.write(to_write.encode("utf-8"))
```

that was my pb recently.

Comment: did you import anything in particular to supplement the utf-8 usage? I tried this in a few different ways and it didn't work.

Comment: No I didn't. But you apparently found a way didn't you ?

Comment: yeah works well. Now the concern is getting it to work with other news sources.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of problems:

```
for tag in tags:
    f.write(tag.get_text() + '\n' + '\n')
```

needs to be indented further (it should be a child of `with open('ctp_output.txt', 'w') as f:`;

```
txt.close()
```

is redundant - the `with` statement already ensures the file gets closed;

I don't see anything missing from the output - can you cite a sentence that disappears?

**Edit:** this looks like a Python3 problem - it works perfectly in Python 2.7.5

**Edit2:** fixed with str.decode():

---

Your code could be simplified to

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import sys
if sys.hexversion < 0x3000000:
    # Python 2.x
    from urllib2 import urlopen
    inp = raw_input
else:
    # Python 3.x
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    inp = input

def get_paras(url):
    page = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
    return [para.get_text() for para in soup('p')]

def write_lst(f, lst, fmt="{}\n\n".format):
    for item in lst:
        f.write(fmt(item))

def main():
    url   = inp("Please enter a fully qualified URL: ")
    fname = inp("Please enter the output file name: ")

    with open(fname, "w") as outf:
        write_lst(outf, get_paras(url))

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: See comment above. It writes everything up to the first quoted paragraph starting with "The president said:

Comment: The output error I get from the console is: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 21-23: ordinal not in range(128) --- Maybe this is causing it to break and exit the loop?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to truncate my code into something more efficient. I got my code working with txt.encode but will incorporate your changes once I get other aspects functioning. Any idea why the edited version of my code wouldn't work with a NY times article? I changed the values that I was scraping to fit the site, but it seems to come back with a multitude of error messages. Here is the article in question: http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/08/sports/olympics/ukraine-wont-boycott-paralympics-in-russia.html?ref=world

Comment: Here are the first of what looks like 50 error messages: soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 410, in open

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 21-23: ordinal not in range(128)` after **Hugh Bothwell's** modification then just also do the following

Use `codecs.open()` or `io.open()` to open a text file using an appropriate text encoding (i.e. encoding="...") instead of opening a bytefile with open().

```
fp=codecs.open('ctp_output.txt', 'w',encoding="utf-8")
```

and just write

```
fp.write("what you want to write")
```

You will need to `import codecs` for this